# How do I bridge a platform version difference between sandbox and production?

Tags: sandbox, change-set, app

I was tasked with adding an app from the app exchange.  As part of that process, I need to create a new trigger in the sandbox, and then move that to production via a change set.  However, when I try to upload that to production, I'm getting an error:

> error  All components failed Version Compatibility Check. Every
>   component in this change set requires the "29.0" or higher platform
>   version. Please select an organization with a platform version of
>   "29.0" or higher.

Looks like my production version is 28.0, but sandbox is 29.0.

What's the best course of action here?   Should I update production?
If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Couldn't you just change the metadata for the trigger to v.28? are you using any syntax specific to v29?

Comment: Looks like that would work as well, phil.  I got that answer elsewhere and applied it.

Comment: Phil, do you want to re-post your comment as an answer, to make it easier to find for future visitors with the same questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're smack in the middle of a release cycle for the Winter '14 release of Salesforce, which brings version 29.0 of the API. Sandboxes are typically upgraded at least a month in advance of the production release, which is why your code in the sandbox is on version 29.0. You can choose your API version however on your metadata components. You have two options:

1) roll back your code to version 28.0 of the API to deploy now.

2) Wait for your instance to be upgraded to Winter '14, either this weekend or next weekend. The release schedule can be determined for your server at http://trust.salesforce.com/

Comment: It's worth noting that if you follow the Sandbox Preview instructions, you can avoid this hassle and keep your Sandbox on the same version as your production environment. Also, of course, this is only a problem for approximately 25% of the year (depending on the number of releases in a year) if you do use the Sandbox Preview.

Answer (score 4):

Solution copied from another answer since this question ranks highest in Google for the error and we're in the midst of the Winter release.

> I've just amended the trigger. Go to Setup> Develop> Apex
>   Triggers>(SelectTrigger) Edit> Click Version Settings> Change Version
>   to 32.0> Save. Deployed Successfully

Source: [Changeset Error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63908/changeset-error)

Answer (score 0):

in sandbox go to your trigger and click edit
go to version settings tab
in Salesforce.com API select the version you are running in Production
hit save
move change set.