# Changeset Error

Tags: apex, trigger, change-set

This change set contains components that require the "33.0" or higher platform version. Please select an organization with a platform version of "33.0" or higher, or remove all incompatible components.

How to resolve it without the need to remove and upload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means API 33 has not yet been released to the target org yet.

Go back to your source org from where you are building your change set. Edit all the classes/ trigger/ vf pages and click on version settings and from the picklist option that says " Salesforce.com API" choose 32.0 as the version instead of 33.0.

Why does this happen?

Anytime you create a new class/page/ trigger salesforce automatically takes the latest and greatest version as default for the new class. This API version may not have been released on the target org.

How to resolve it without the need to remove and upload?

You cannot resolve this without rebuilding your change set. You need to downgrade the API version of the metadata in the source org save the metadata, then clone the previously uploaded change set and push it to target org for deployment.

Comment: I've just amended the trigger. Go to Setup> Develop> Apex Triggers>(SelectTrigger) Edit> Click Version Settings> Change Version to 32.0> Save. Deployed Successfully